# Remove special characters (char(10),CHAR(13),CHAR(160),CHAR(9)) while uploading data from Excel on ADF Data flow

Tags: azure, ascii, azure-data-factory, special-characters, dataflow

I am trying to remove ascii characters while uploading data from Excel by using rule based mapping on ADF data flow for all string characters but i got error on 'unknown function' like below screenshot. What is the best practicals to do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: CHAR() is not a valid function in ADF data flows. Instead, use regexReplace().

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Kromer MSFT mentioned in the comments, there is no CHAR() function available in the Azure data factory.

Alternatively, replace the char characterusing replace() or regexReplace() function in data flow.

Example:

[image]

[image]

[image]